# Refactoring gatsby-node.js promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, gatsby

I'm working on a project of mines which I started from a free template from the Gatsby site. I wanted to create a blog section in it, nothing too complicated, so I kind of tried to copy what was already there but it doesn't work as I would, I'm creating three different context for three different pages and It's kind of hard to understand, in fact the index page of the blog sometimes has wrong queries showing. I'm pretty sure I'm not that master of Javascript promises, can somebody help? if you do I will much appreciate, have a look at this code

```
const path = require(`path`);
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        graphql(`
      {
        allDatoCmsWork {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
            }
          }
        }

        allDatoCmsBlog {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
              article
              title
              date
              category
            }
          }
        }
    }
    `).then((result) => {

            result.data.allDatoCmsWork.edges.map(({ node: work }) => {
                createPage({
                    path: `works/${work.slug}`,
                    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/work.js`),
                    context: {
                        slug: work.slug,
                    },
                });
            });

            result.data.allDatoCmsBlog.edges.map(({ node }) => {
                createPage({
                    path: `blog/${node.slug}`,
                    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/article.js`),
                    context: {
                        slug: node.slug,
                    },
                });
                createPage({
                    path: `blog/${node.category}`,
                    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/gather-category.js`),
                    context: {
                        category: node.category
                    }
                });
            });
            resolve();
        });
    });



};
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? I don't see too much wrong in this code. Might be the page query that run that is incorrect

Comment: Hi @LaurensKling I was not getting any error from the console, but sometimes after hitting different routes and going back to the main blog page, I was having my gather-category rendered for `/blog` route so couldn't go back either. I found a fix for that, in any case I'm new to promises...

Comment: Hit the gatsby debug 404 page to see what pages are created. It might help you in understanding which pages are created and which aren't

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {

  const result = await graphql(`
      {
        allDatoCmsWork {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
            }
          }
        }

        allDatoCmsBlog {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
              article
              title
              date
              category
            }
          }
        }
    }
    `)
    .then((result) => {

      result.data.allDatoCmsWork.edges.map(({ node: work }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `works/${work.slug}`,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/work.js`),
          context: {
            slug: work.slug,
          },
        });
      });

      result.data.allDatoCmsBlog.edges.map(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `blog/${node.slug}`,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/article.js`),
          context: {
            slug: node.slug,
          },
        });
        createPage({
          path: `blog/${node.category}`,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/gather-category.js`),
          context: {
            category: node.category
          }
        });
      });
    });
};
```

Note the promise-based approach with `async` and `await` functions because `graphql` function calls returns a Promise.  See: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise%20for) more info.

Comment: Thanks @FerranBuireu I also tried storing every promise in a variable and than returning all three variables at the end

Comment: Yes, the approach is the same. I've put in the same promise because your trial was about this. Of course, it's better to splice them into three separate promises since they can run in parallel.